# How can I enable draggable when mouse is already down on element and already moved?

Tags: javascript, html, draggable

I have code written to allow an HTML element to be dragged after the mouse has been down over that element for a certain period of time.

The problem is that when I am using native HTML drag and drop, and I enable the `draggable` property when this timeout is up (the mouse has been down on that element for that period of time), if the mouse had been moved while it was down before that timeout was up, HTML will not trigger a `dragstart` event or even start dragging the element.

There is an example below.

```js
var t;

function startDelayedDrag() {
  clearTimeout(t);
  document.getElementById('dragtarget').draggable = false;
  console.log('mousedown')
  t = setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('dragging enabled')
    document.getElementById('dragtarget').draggable = true;
  }, 1000);
}
```

```css
.droptarget {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="droptarget">
  <p onmousedown="startDelayedDrag()" id="dragtarget">Drag me!</p>
</div>

<div class="droptarget"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is tricky and it might be different from what you had in mind, but here is goes an idea how to solve your issue:

1. Start the drag event
2. Hide the drag object by setting an image using `setDragImage`
3. Clone the drag element node, hide the clone and add it to the document (since it's not possible to change the image set by `setDragImage`)
4. Start the timeout to change the visibility of the ghost element

This could be yet improved in many ways, but I think you can get the mechanics of how it works as it is. As a reference see the following snippet:

```js
const [$drag] = document.getElementsByClassName('drag')
const [$pixel] = document.getElementsByClassName('pixel')
let $ghost = null

$drag.addEventListener("dragstart", e => {
  // set the current draged element invisible
  e.dataTransfer.setDragImage($pixel, 0, 0)
  
  // create a ghost element
  $ghost = $drag.cloneNode(true)
  $ghost.style.position = "absolute"
  $ghost.style.display = "none"
  document.body.appendChild($ghost)

  setTimeout(() => {
    $ghost.style.display = 'block'
  }, 1000)
})

$drag.addEventListener("drag", e => {
  // keep the ghost position to follow the mouse while dragging 
  $ghost.style.left = `${e.clientX}px`
  $ghost.style.top = `${e.clientY}px`
}, false);

$drag.addEventListener("dragend", e => {
  // remove the ghost
  if ($ghost.parentNode) $ghost.parentNode.removeChild($ghost)
}, false)
```

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

.drop {
  user-select: none;
}

.drag {
  text-align: center;
}

.pixel {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div draggable="true" class="drag box">Drag</div>
  <div class="drop box"></div>
  <div class="pixel"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This isn't *exactly* what I was looking for, but it might be the best solution. I was hoping that it wouldn't actually drag until that timeout was up, so that it wouldn't interfere with other events I have set up. But yeah this might be the best solution, and I will just need a variable to ignore those events until the timeout is up. Thank you for your work.

Comment: @OwenM that's right, it deviates from your initial question since there are some limitations on the current drag API. Anyway, if this solved your question, remember to mark the answer as solved.